# How to search lines of text file for specific keyword and store string to the right hand side of that keyword

Tags: batch-file

I am new to windows batch scripting and am having trouble extracting information from a text file. My script needs to iterate over a text file with an unknown number of lines and search for the string "Installer ID:". Once this is found I need to store whatever information is on the right hand side of the colon.

For example if my text file looked as follows:

```
SomeText.txt
------------------------
Installer Date: 2010_10_24_24345
OXF BUILD ID: OXF-12223
Installer ID: OTFI-316
Excel  ID: 2-10186
BUILD DBID: 296414
Version: 6.2
```

I would want to store:

```
OTFI-316
```

I have come so far with something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=build_info.txt
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (%file%) DO (
findstr Installer ID: %%i
if %errorlevel%==0 (
set installer_id=SUBSTRING I
)
```

but I am having problems searching %%i for "Installer ID:" with its two words and colon, and from there I am unsure how to properly substring %%i.

Comment: Is the %%1 in your FOR an error?  Did you mean to write %%i?

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo, I had tried some other things there that didn't pan out so I just wanted to revert to something simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the FINDSTR command within the FOR IN() clause, and parse the results.

I set DELIMS to colon and space so that all of the following lines would give the correct result:

```
Installer ID: OTFI-316
Installer ID:OTFI-316
Installer ID:      OTFI-316
```

You want everything after the 2nd token (the `*` in `tokens=2*`).

```
@echo off
set "file=build_info.txt"
set "installer_id="
for /f "tokens=2* delims=: " %%A in (
  'findstr /bc:"Installer ID:" "%file%"'
) do set "installer_id=%%B"
```

Comment: I like this answer it is clean and clear. Just to talk it out and be thorough in my understanding, your FOR loop iterates over a set of lines in SomeText.txt that contains "Installer ID:". The command then sets %installer_id% to the third->Nth token of the last "Installer ID:" line, with a token being delimited by spaces, Correct? I used two different file names in my examples but is there a reason you specified "file=build_info.txt" but searched "SomeText.txt"? Also can you explain what a set enclosed by quotations signifies?

Comment: @user1595254 - Oops, I intended to search `"%file%"`. I've corrected the answer. It sounds like you understand, except the delimiter is both space and colon. Consecutive delimiters count as just one delimiter - they don't yield empty tokens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that it's treating Installer and ID as separate commands.  What's more, the : after ID means it's treating ID: as a drive. To get around it, enclose Installer ID: in quotes.

For example, if I have a text file called test.txt with the following contents:

```
Test
abcinstaller ID:xyz
Test 2
```

Then I can search it with:

```
findstr "Installer ID:" test.txt
```

And it returns:

```
abcinstaller ID:xyz
```

Comment: When I try this it tells me "FINDSTR cannot open X" with X being each individual token in my text file. Can I tell findstr to search a string and not a file? Should I be searching the file directly and avoiding the FOR loop breaking it into individual lines?

Comment: The rest of your text was lost.  What did it tell you?

Comment: Okay that makes more sense, however I am seeing "Installer ID:" still treated as two different words. If we use my original SomeText.txt example searching it using FINDSTR "Installer ID:" returns every line that has "Installer" or "ID:" in it.... so I would also see "OXF BUILD ID: OXF-12223, Excel ID: 2-10186, BUILD DBID: 296414"

Comment: Have you tried putting two findstr, one for Installer and one for ID?

Comment: How would that actually be written? I tried nesting FINDSTR but that return odd results. How can I actually store a value that a FINDSTR prints out? If I could store that to a variable then I think I could call FINDSTR again no problem.

Comment: Well, you could redirect them to a file.  Here's a link with some more info: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/230090-45-windows-batch-file-output-program-variable

Answer (score 0):

As user1595254 suggested, I use FINDSTR to locate what I need and write that to a temporary file. I then set my var to the that temp file:

```
@echo off
findstr "Installer" build_info.txt > findstr_results
findstr "ID" findstr_results> installer_id
set /p installer_id= < installer_id
del findstr_results
del installer_id
echo %installer_id%
```